# What does greater<pair<int,int>> do actually?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have encountered this `greater<pair<int,int>>` in many codes.
For example, in the initialisation of the priority queue [code below]

```
priority_queue<pair<int,int>, vector<pair<int,int>>, greater<pair<int,int>>> pq;
```

I tried a lot of googling but still couldn't find the best answer.

Comment: [Decent docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater).

Comment: It represents the act of comparing two pairs of integers, in order to decide which pair of integers is greater than the other.

Comment: `std::pair` isn't directly comparable, is it? There has to be an operator overload that exists somewhere as well.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp

Answer (score 3):

This is the [`std::greater`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater) type.

This is a function object type that does comparisons using the `>` operator. A rough implementation looks like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct greater {
    constexpr auto operator()(T const& a, T const& b) const -> bool {
        return a > b; // greater operator
    }
};
```

In your example, this is being used to order the `std::pair`s in the `priority_queue` from "smallest" to "largest" using `std::pair`'s [`operator >`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp).

Answer (score 2):

The std::greater is a template function object defined as:

```
template<typename T> struct greater {
    constexpr bool operator()(T const& a, T const& b) const {
        return a > b; // greater operator
    }
};
```

Now, the '>' operator is defined for std::pair as -

```
template <class T1, class T2>
  bool operator>  (const pair<T1,T2>& lhs, const pair<T1,T2>& rhs)    { return rhs<lhs; }
```

Now, the '<' operator is defined as-

```
template <class T1, class T2>
  bool operator<  (const pair<T1,T2>& lhs, const pair<T1,T2>& rhs)
{ return lhs.first<rhs.first || (!(rhs.first<lhs.first) && lhs.second<rhs.second); }
```

So, **effectively**, the function greater<pair<int, int>> works as-

```
template<typename T> struct greater {
        constexpr bool operator()(T const& a, T const& b) const {
            return a.first>b.first || ( (a.first<b.first) && (a.second>b.second));
        }
    };
```

That is, greater<pair<int, int>>(a, b) returns true if and only if the 'first' parameter of a is greater than b or if 'first' parameters are equal then 'second' parameter of a is greater than b.
This is a **strict weak ordering**.

Comment: Hi, in the third code block, shouldn't it be return a.first>b.first || ( (a.first==b.first) && (a.second>b.second));

Comment: @VD26 Your answer is mathematically correct, but misses a few syntactical points.
In C++, when the || operator is evaluated, the right side term is evaluated only if left term is found to be false. Therefore, right term is only evaluated when a.first>=b.first. (Note that >= operator here is not used in syntactical way, it is used in mathematical way). Therefore, a.first < b.first in right side term will evaluate to true only if a.first < b.first and a.first > b.first. This is mathematically equivalent to a.first==b.first. We don't simply use '==' to avoid cyclic dependencies among operators.